# How to access and manipulate Google to-do list?

Tags: android, google-tasks-api

I need to access Google's todo list from Android programmatically. Please give me some clue where to start, and some examples if possible. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean Google Tasks, check out [Google Tasks API](http://code.google.com/apis/tasks/index.html)

EDIT: Please read the answer to [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214917/android-problem-to-access-google-tasks-with-oauth), you might find it interesting